# Unable to access Struct contents properly

Tags: c, struct, parameter-passing

I am not getting the string output from the following:

```
struct stringItem {
    int len;
    char str[1];
}
```

```
void allocationStringBuffer (char* stringContent, struct stringItem *string) {

    // dynamically sized object
    int n;
    n = strlen(stringContent);

    //struct stringItem *string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + n);
    string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + n);

    if (string == NULL) {             // check if malloc is successful
       printf("Memory allocation for string fails.\n");
       // exit(-1);
    }   

   strcpy(string->str, stringContent);
   printf("Struct string: %s\n", string->str);
   string->len = n;     
}
```

in main:

```
struct stringItem *string2;

allocationStringBuffer ("helloWorld", string2);

printf("Struct string: %s\n", (*string2).str);
free(string2);

allocationStringBuffer ("another Statement...", string2);
printf("Struct string: %s\n", string2->str);
free(string2);
```

The result is:

```
Struct string: helloWorld
Struct string:  ÉÉÉÉÉï Uï∞â∞¶SVWh♦☺
Struct string: another Statement...
Struct string:  ÉÉÉÉÉï Uï∞â∞¶SVWh♦☺
```

Thank you for your help.

```
[Updates with Thanks to ALL]
Here is the full working code. It has been resolved. Thank you to ALL.

struct stringItem {
    int len;
    char str[1];
};


void allocationStringBuffer (char* stringContent, struct stringItem** pstring) {

    // dynamically sized object
    int n;
    n = strlen(stringContent);

    struct stringItem *string;
    string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + (n+1));

    if (string == NULL) {             // check if malloc is successful
       printf("Memory allocation for string fails.\n");
       // exit(-1);
    }   

   strcpy(string->str, stringContent);
   printf("Struct string: %s\n", string->str);
   string->len = n;     

   *pstring = string;  // Copy allocated pointer to out-parameter.
}
```

in main

struct stringItem *string2;

allocationStringBuffer ("helloWorld", &string2);

printf("Struct string: %s\n", (*string2).str);
free(string2);

allocationStringBuffer ("another Statement...", &string2);
printf("Struct string: %s\n", string2->str);
free(string2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to make these changes:

```
allocationStringBuffer ("helloWorld", &string2);  // Pass ADDRESS of string2, not just string2
```

---

```
void allocationStringBuffer (char* stringContent, struct stringItem **pstring)
{
    // dynamically sized object
    int n;
    n = strlen(stringContent);

    struct stringItem* string;  // Local variable, will be later copied to function parameter.
    string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + n);

    if (string == NULL) {             // check if malloc is successful
       printf("Memory allocation for string fails.\n");
       // exit(-1);
    }   

   strcpy(string->str, stringContent);
   printf("Struct string: %s\n", string->str);
   string->len = n;     

   *pstring = string;  // Copy allocated pointer to out-parameter.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the terminating null character in your **malloc** call.

```
string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + (n + 1));
```

**strlen** gives you the size without including the terminating null character.

Regards,

Comment: Nope... if that were it, we'd expect the string to print properly, then see garbage after the end of it.  That is not the described output.

Comment: You are right, this was not the main problem but it is a problem too.

Comment: It entirely depends on how `struct stringItem` is defined  *(too bad poster has not shown us the structure definition!)*  If it is `struct stringItem { int len; char str[1]; }`, then the +1 is not needed.  It is already built into the struct.   (**PS** This is a very common structure definition in pre-C89 code, when dealing with network protocols)

Comment: Now that the poster has posted the definition, we see it did have `char str[1];` built into the definition.  So sizeof(struct stringItem) already has space for the terminating null, and we only have to add the `strlen` of the source-string.

Comment: Yes, in this case we don't need to reserve the space for the terminating null char on the malloc.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a pointer to stringItem to the function, then overwriting the parameter with the return from `malloc`, then dropping it thus leaking its memory.  You have two options to solve this:

```
void allocationStringBuffer(char* stringContent, struct stringItem** string) {
    int length = strlen(stringContent);
    *string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + length + 1);
    /* The +1 is padding.  You do want that. */
    strcpy(*string->str, stringContent);
}
```

or:

```
struct stringItem* allocationStringBuffer(char* stringContent) {
    int length = strlen(stringContent);
    struct stringItem* string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + length + 1);
    strcpy(string->str, stringContent);
    return string;
}
```

Basically, you have to return the pointer you're `malloc`ing some way or another.  You can't send it a pointer to a `stringItem` on the stack (i.e. a local variable) like you're doing.

Comment: I like your idea of returning the allocated pointer better than the answer i gave, of passing a pointer-to-a-pointer. Good choice!

Comment: @UrsaMajor nope!  I don't have the requisite definition of `struct stringItem`, so it isn't going to compile.  Regardless, not returning the pointer is going to be a problem, no?

Answer (score 0):

This one seems not right:

```
string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem) + n);
```

What are you trying to do here? `string` is an element of `struct stringItem`. So I think you just need to allocate `string = malloc(sizeof(struct stringItem));`

p/s: i should be good if you post your declaration of struct stringItem as well